# Regex - Matching a part of a URL

Tags: regex

I'm trying to use regular expression to match a part of the following url:

> http://www.example.com/store/store.html?ptype=lst&id=370&3434323&root=nav_3&dir=desc&order=popularity

I want the Regex to find:

```
&3434323
```

Basically, it's meant to search any part of the argument that doesn't follow the `variable=value` formula. So basically I need it to search sections of the URL that don't have an equal sign it, but match just that part.

I tried using:

> &\w*+[^=_-]

But it returns: **&3434323&**. I need it to not return the next ampersand.

And it must be done in regex. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please post your attempt.

Comment: Which regex dialect (read: programming language) should this work for? Is there a specific reason that you’re recreating by hand something that there are surely easier-to-use libraries for? Certainly there are cases where you can specify only a regex but not library code, but I wonder whether this is actually one of those, or if you're putting yourself through too much trouble. Try [this search](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bregex%5D+parse+url) and add a tag for whatever programming language you’re using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this regex:

```
[?&][^=]+(&|$)
```

It looks for any string that doesn't contain the equal sing `[^=]+` and starts with the question mark or the ampersand `[?&]` and ends with ampersand or the end of the URL `(&|$)`.

Please note that this will return `&3434323&`, so you'll have to strip the ampersands on both sides in your code. I assume that you're fine with that. If you really don't want the second ampersand, you can use a lookahead:

```
[?&][^=]+(?=&|$)
```

If you don't want even the first ampersand, you can use this regex, but not all compilers support it:

```
(?<=\?|&)[^=]+(?=&|$)
```

Answer (score 2):

Parsing query parameters can be tricky, but this may do the job:

```
((?:[?&])[^=&]+)(?=&|$)
```

It will not catch the ampersand at the end of the parameter, but it will include either the question mark or the ampersand at the beginning. It will match any parameter not in the form of a key-value pair.

Demo [here](https://regex101.com/r/IVihOo/3).

Comment: Please be aware that most regex compilers don’t know to optimize single-codepoint alternatives like your `(?:\?|&)` into `[?&]` for the greatly improved performance usually afforded by the latter compared with the former.